# Function is not returning 'China UnionPay', not sure why

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

My function takes in a card number that is a string and returns the name of the card. Every card seems to be working but the China Pay one. I am getting undefined, not sure why. There are about 800 China Pay prefixes. I iterated through those 800 numbers and pushed them in to an empty array that I then searched the index of. If it matches one of the prefixes in the array and one of the two lengths it should return the name but its not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this but this is where my brain went. It should work, not sure why it's not.

```
  // loop through the 800 numbers and push to an empty array
  var chinaPayPrefix = [];
  for (let i = 622126; i <= 622925; i++){
    let chinaPayStringOne = i.toString();
    chinaPayPrefix.push(chinaPayStringOne);
  }
  for (let j = 6282; j <= 6288; j++){
    let chinaPayStringTwo = j.toString();
    chinaPayPrefix.push(chinaPayStringTwo);
  }
  // card lengths
  const discoverCardLength = [16,19];
  const maestroCardLength = [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19];
  const visaCardLength = [13,16,19];
  const masterCardLength = 16;
  const dinersCardLength = 14;
  const americanExpressLength = 15;
  const chinaPayLength = [16,19];
  // card prefixes
  const discoverPrefix = ['6011','644','645','646','647','648','649','65'];
  const maestroPrefix = ['5018','5020','5038','6304'];
  const visaPrefix = ['4'];
  const mastercardPrefix = ['51','52','53','54','55'];
  const dinersPrefix = ['38', '39'];
  const americanExpressPrefix = ['34', '37'];
  // substrings of cardNumber
  let singleSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,1);
  let doubleSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,2);
  let tripleSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,3);
  let quadSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,4);
  let sextupleSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,7);
  // search if the applicable substring is present and length is correct
  if (dinersPrefix.indexOf(doubleSplit) > -1 && cardNumber.length === dinersCardLength) {
    return 'Diner\'s Club';
  } else if (americanExpressPrefix.indexOf(doubleSplit) > -1 && cardNumber.length === americanExpressLength) {
    return 'American Express';
  } else if (visaPrefix.indexOf(singleSplit) > -1 && visaCardLength.indexOf(cardNumber.length) > - 1){
    return 'Visa';
  } else if (mastercardPrefix.indexOf(doubleSplit) > -1 && cardNumber.length === masterCardLength){
    return 'MasterCard';
  } else if (discoverPrefix.indexOf(doubleSplit) > -1 || discoverPrefix.indexOf(tripleSplit) > -1 || discoverPrefix.indexOf(quadSplit) > -1 && discoverCardLength.indexOf(cardNumber.length) > - 1){
    return 'Discover';
  } else if (maestroPrefix.indexOf(quadSplit) > - 1 && maestroCardLength.indexOf(cardNumber.length) > - 1){
    return 'Maestro';
  } else if (chinaPayPrefix.indexOf(sextupleSplit) > - 1 && chinaPayLength.indexOf(cardNumber.length) > - 1){
    return 'China UnionPay';
  }else if (chinaPayPrefix.indexOf(quadSplit) > - 1 && chinaPayLength.indexOf(cardNumber.length) > - 1){
    return 'China UnionPay';
  }else if (chinaPayPrefix.indexOf(tripleSplit) > - 1 && chinaPayLength.indexOf(cardNumber.length) > - 1){
    return 'China UnionPay';
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you debug the code using dev tools? Please provide the value of `cardNumber` for which you have a problem.

Comment: detectNetwork('6229008767564345'); should return the China Pay card, it doesn't...just returns undefined. I've only been programming a couple months and am not very good at chrome dev tools. I am going to do some studying on it today.

Answer (score 0):

```
let sextupleSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,7);
```

should be

```
let sextupleSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,6);
```

to only take the first 6 digits

quadSplit and tripleSplit are ok

Comment: @crfriedt, honestly, this is not so wow. You can easily detect this if you debug your code. Now you have just asked others to do it for you, but really, this should be part of your programming habits.

Comment: gotcha, appreciate it. I'll get better at debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This line for 6 characters:

```
let sextupleSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,7);
```

should be

```
let sextupleSplit = cardNumber.substring(0,6)
```